# Suggestions on pub/sub architecture with high availability

Tags: architecture, messaging, publish-subscribe, high-availability

This seems to be a quite generic problem but I was unable to find answer yet. Suppose I have a publish/subscribe infrastructure in place and one of the component of the solution has to take actions upon receiving messages on the topic (action should be taken only once per message). It is also important that the component is highly available and with active-active semantic for load balancing.

With P2P messaging pattern it's quite easy to achieve this by running multiple instances of consumer listening to same queue. However, with pub/sub each instance of consumer will receive its own copy of message thus same action might be executed multiple times.

The approach I'm thinking about is to have separate component which would run in active-passive mode and translate pub/sub into P2P by forwarding messages to queue (it could be either another broker or even something like Redis). Between two instances of the translator will be a heartbeat message that will allow passive instance to subscribe to topic as soon as active instance disconnects for whatever reason.

Another option is to have shared storage between all active instances and as soon as one instance started to process message it will indicate this in the storage so other instances will just drop the message from processing. I'm afraid that this would cause lot of contention issues rendering benefits of active-active configuration to none.

I'm looking for the suggestions on the other approaches or maybe refinements to the ones I've listed down.

Comment: Does this help? http://knolleary.net/2012/04/11/queuing-with-mqtt/

Comment: This is helpful indeed and I think this article resembles the first approach. It does not, however, solves the high-availability part for a single topic subscriber so that would still have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit unclear what guarantees do you have from your producer (pub/sub). Can it support durable subscriptions?

For your availability requirements the first solution is probably more feasible. Implementing leader election protocol is a really hard problem to solve. I would recommend to use existing solution like Zookeeper for that. No matter how you choose to do it you will need at least 3 members for leader election. E.g. 3 Zookeeper nodes.

Database lock option will contribute to your latency and again for your availability requirements you will need to setup cluster.

Comment: I will take a look into Zookeeper. In this case some kind of queuing infrastructure would have to be put in place. Redis probably will be one of the options.